# How can I add a marker or meshpoint to the start and end of a ListLinePlot or DateListPlot

Tags: plotting, legending, mesh, marker

How can I add a marker or meshpoint to the start and end of a line in `ListLinePlot` or `DateListPlot`?

I would like to be able specify the marker type, eg. a circle for the start and a cross for the end.

I would like the solution to generalise to ListLinePlot, DateListPlot and also where the path might be a `TimeSeries` object

```
data = {-253, -219, -303, -333, -333, -340, -298, -229, -203, -150, -121, -113, -52, -67, -25, 180, 129};
time = Range@Length@data;
path = Transpose@{time, data};
ListLinePlot[path]
```

An example of a desired plot:

[image: Example of desired output]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$Version

"14.0.0 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (December 13, 2023)"

Clear["Global`*"]

data = {-253, -219, -303, -333, -333, -340, -298, -229, -203, -150, \
-121, -113, -52, -67, -25, 180, 129};
time = Range@Length@data;
path = Transpose@{time, data};

ListLinePlot[{path, {path[[1]]}, {path[[-1]]}},
 PlotMarkers -> {"", 
   Style["O", ColorData[97][2], 12, Bold], 
   Style["X", ColorData[97][2], 12, Bold]}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

To draw some markers you can use "Epilog". However, you need to know the scaling, the x and y spread of the data. You get this by:

```
spread = MinMax /@ {time, data};
spread = -Subtract @@@ spread

{16, 520}
```

Using this you can draw markers, e.g. circles, with appropriate scaling. Eventually you need a bit of padding, so that the whole marker is displayed:

```
ListLinePlot[path, 
 Epilog -> {Green, Circle[path[[1]], 0.03 spread], 
   Circle[path[[-1]], 0.03  spread]}, PlotRangePadding -> {1, 0}]
```

[image]

Comment: You could also use `Scaled[.03]`, rather than calculating the spread

Comment: @MelaGo  You are right, this is simpler. +1

Answer (score 3):

Since the x-coordinates range from `1` to the length of the `data`, a trimmed down implementation could be:

```
data = {-253, -219, -303, -333, -333, -340, -298, -229, -203, -150, \
-121, -113, -52, -67, -25, 180, 129};

ListLinePlot[data
 , Epilog -> {
   Red, Circle[{1, data[[1]]}, Offset[6]]
   , Blue, Text[Style["X", 16], {Length@data, data[[-1]]}]
   }
 ]
```

---

[image]